# Python Pandas: How I can unique my table only based on certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a df :

How can I remove duplicates based on of only one column? Because I have rows that all of their columns are the same but only one is not. I want to ignore that column and get the unique values based on the other column?

That is how I tried but I get an error on it:

```
data.drop_duplicates('asn','first_seen','incident_type','ip','uri')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of `pandas` are you running? I believe that since `>0.14` you should provide a list of columns to `drop_duplicates()` using the `subset` keyword, so try

`data.drop_duplicates(subset=['asn','first_seen','incident_type','ip','uri'])`

Also note that if you are not using `inplace=True` you will need to assign the returned value to a new dataframe.

Depending on your needs, you may also want to call `reset_index()` after dropping the duplicate rows.